# send front/back not always working on OSx 10.10 and 10.11

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

I have an App originally created on `OS X 10.9` with `XCode 6`. In the App I have an `NSTabView` with multiple tabs. Each tab has a `Custom` `View`, a Subclass of `NSView`, that fills the entire window. Also, each tab has an `NSTable`, `NSButton`, `NSLabels`, etc... I've sent the `NSView` to the back and ensured all items are in the correct order on each tab. I've been running the App on `OS X 10.9` for over a year with no issues.

I opened the App on a new MBP with `OS X 10.11` and on the first tab the `NSTable` and `Label` are not visible - covered by the `NSView`, all the other tabs are correct. Closed and opened the App and the tab is correct. Close and open again and it's either good or not - unpredictable.

This only happens on one of the tabs. Tried the App on a `MBP` with `OS X` `10.10` and the same issue as OS X 10.11 - sometimes the `NSTable` and other objects are covered by the `NSView` and sometimes not. Everything works without issue on OS X 10.9.

As another check, I archived and exported the App from `Xcode 7` on the MBP with `OS X 10.11` - same issue. Ran that version on `OS X 10.9` - no issue.

=[EDIT]===
In Interface builder, here is the layout:

```
  Main Tab View

    -General (This is Tab 1)

      -View

         -tabBGColorView (This is the custom View, subclass of NSView)

         -Bordered Scroll View

         -General (NSTextField)
```

Select `tabBGColorView`, then `Editor/Arrange => Send Backwards/to`

- Back are grayed
- send forward/to Front are available.

Sometimes the order is correct at runtime, other times it is not - unpredictable.

I have another solution for the `BGColor` of the Tab, sub classing `NSTabView`,  which I have implemented and appears to be working well. However, that solution does not answer the original question.

Comment: Is the custom view a subview of the view of the tab? Are all subviews of the first tab not visible? What happens if you switch the first and second tab? Do you do anything in code? What is your question?

Comment: My question is - why is the view order in my App inconsistently working beginning in OS X 10.10? The custom view is a subview of the Tab and yes, all subviews in the one tab are randomly either visible or not. All the other tabs are setup similar and they always work properly. The custom view is the same size as the Tab, all other subview are on top/in front of the custom view. One of the purposes of the custom view is to can change the background color of the tab.

Comment: Your initial question was edited away. Apple probably changed some things in 10.10 to make NSTabViewController work. Is the order of the subviews what you expect, in the xib and runtime?

Comment: @Willeke - I edited the question to provide more detail.